# Google authorship not working on the google search

Tags: google-plus, google-authentication

I have strange issue in my blog. I tried to implement google authorship for my blog and added proper publisher link as follows.

```
 <link href="https://plus.google.com/NNNNNNNNNNN" rel="publisher" />
```

Then added author link as follows

```
<span class="vcard author"><span class="fn"  itemprop="name"><a href="https://plus.google.com/NNNNNNNN" rel="author">jobin jose</a></span></span>
```

Then i choose email verification method and verified.

Also it added in the plus profile contributor section.

Then i check with structured Data Tool the thumbnail is showing but the following errors showing

Email verification has not established authorship for this webpage.

Email address on the mydomain.com domain has been verified on this profile: Yes

Public contributor-to link from Google+ profile to mydomain.com: Yes

Automatically detected author name on webpage: Not Found.

The name in my google plus account and here are same then how this error ?
Please help me to solve this issue last one week working on this ! :(

my site link [here](http://www.walkswithme.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its get worked.
I didn't do anything extra for this. after few days its works but on the structured Data Tool 
showing same error on search  its working fine.. :) :) :)

[here](http://www.walkswithme.net/) is the link